Compute p-vale from beta, standard error, sample size and number of regression parameters
How do I compute the p-value if I only know the  beta (i.e., the regression coefficient from a linear regression), the standard error, the sample size, and the number of regression parameters?
And, is there any other method, than p-values, through which I can determine statistical significance?
